# The container >...< references non existing library in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova

I try to install [this phonegap plugin from github](https://github.com/champy/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner), but when I refer the imported project in my project as a library (step 3 in the readme file), i get the error shown above.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I clicked "ok" instead of "apply" in the library settings, and now it seems to work, the error disapperad.

Can somebody help me with this: When I try to run the project, this is my code in the index.html`s head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result) {
    alert("We got a barcode\n" +
              "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
              "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
              "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
}, function(error) {
    alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
}
);
}
</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
11-05 12:22:23.641: E/Web Console(454): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PhoneGap at file:///android_asset/www/barcodescanner.js:57
```

the file is from the bar code scanner plugin. Its in the correct folder (project/assets/www). Somebody would help with this, would be great.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that, you have not specified the correct path for your phonegap-XX.js in your maain HTML file.

This is related to : [phonegap barcode scanner plugin -> Reference Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019897/phonegap-barcode-scanner-plugin-reference-error/8911138)

Answer (score 1):

The new BarcodeScanner plugin depends upon an Android Library project. My partner recently updated this step-by-step tutorial for the latest BarcodeScanner plugin -> [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3).

Comment: From author of above-mentioned tutorial: I tried to reproduce your error, but could not. On creating library project, did you select "create project from existing source" in the Create Android Project window? RE: README.md Step 2 - I found that Is Library was already checked.

Comment: @Libby: yes, I did as you said. I just tryed on a different computer, same problem :/. Does the downloaded package has to be in a certain directory, like the workspace when I import it?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter where you download/unzip the plugin. What's important is creating the java package, importing java file, and configuring projects as library or including a library. If you copied files from outside Eclipse then a File->Refresh may be needed. Wondering what version of Android SDK Tools you are at (Window->Android SDK Manager)?

Comment: SDK Tools Revision 15, I didnt create a package before, wasnt I supposed to import the entire project (from existing source)?